# Why does the code throw illegal memory access error

Tags: c++, quicksort

I want to know why the error appears when the code just gets into the function '
sort'

I made some check points using standard output. So I know where the error occurs.

I use repl.it to build this code

```
   ...
/*return pivot function*/
int partition(...){
   ...
}
void sort(vector<int> array, int left, int right){\
/*********"sort start" string dose not appear in console***********/
  cout << "sort start";
  // one element in array
  if(left == right);
  // two elements in array
  else if( left +1 == right){
    if(array.at(0) > array.at(1)){
      int temp;
      swap(array.at(0),array.at(1),temp);
    }
  }
  // more then 3 elements in array
  else{
    int p = partition(array,left,right);
    sort(array,left,p-1);
    sort(array,p+1,right);
  }
}
int main() {
  vector<int> array;
  array.push_back(1);
  array.push_back(2); 
  array.push_back(3);
  array.push_back(4);

  cout << "array is ";
  for(int i = 0 ; i < array.size(); i++){
    cout << array.at(i) << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
  sort(array,0,array.size()-1);/***************sort is here*************/
  cout << "sorting..." << endl;
  cout << "array is ";
  for(int i = 0 ; i < array.size(); i++){
    cout << array.at(i) << " ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this code console output is

```
array is 4 3 2 2
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 18446744073709551615) >= 
this->size() (which is 4)
exited, aborted
```

But what I expected is

```
array is 4 3 2 2
sorting...
sort start
array is 2 2 3 4
```

Comment: How could you expect 4 3 2 2 if you push 1 2 3 4 ? Furthermore, your function sort does not take the vector by reference, then the function will sort a copy of you input array.

Comment: You push `1,2,3,4` into `array` and the immediate subsequent output reads `4 3 2 2`? Hard to believe: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZWmOQOjxehWmSQk1.

Comment: what did `partition(array,left,right)` do?

Comment: In the 2-element case you likely want to compare and swap elements with indexes `left` and `right` and not with `0` and `1`. Moreover, you don't check for cases where `left` is higher than `right`, which happens if `p` equals  `left` or `right` after `partition`.

Comment: A good example why `using namespace std` is bad practice. It doesn't look like this could be the reason for error due to a different argument types, but did you know that https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition exists.

Comment: @Anže The same is true for `swap`.

Comment: What makes you so sure that `partition` is correct? And why does your `swap` function take three arguments?

Comment: You do not need a special case for two elements.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is inside `partition`?

Comment: and what is `swap`? why does it take 3 parameters?

Comment: You may need to use `std::cout.flush()` to see the line "sort start". C++ streams can be slow some times. But anyway, your provided output can not possibly  be produced by the provided code as others already mentioned.

Comment: The error must be in `partition` as your `sort` function erroneously only accesses element `0` and `1` which should always work with your input

Comment: @AlanBirtles That's not necessarily true. Consider that after first `partition`, the returned index of pivot `p` is 0 (that might always happen). Then, the next recursive call is `sort(array,left,p-1);`, that is `sort(array,0,-1);`. Now, `sort` should immediately return, but it does not and something wrong will likely happen.

Comment: @DanielLangr what i was saying is that the out of range error can only be thrown from partition as sort never accesses elements other than 0 and 1

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for clarification. I originally understood it a different way, that is that the _error in the code_ must be inside `partition`. Now, your comment makes sense. Anyway, the error message indicates that the accessed index was converted from a negative `int` into unsigned 64-bit value (likely of type `size_t`): https://wandbox.org/permlink/9rzy3XqaJ3NAudNW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an element at index `-1`, which, when converted into 64-bit unsigned value, is `18446744073709551615`. Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/jAhJZS3ANjkDDOUr.

There are multiple problems with your code and, first of all, you don't show us the definition of your `partition` and `swap`. Moreover, your code does not match the provided output (`1 2 3 4` vs `4 3 2 2` in the first line).

Anyway, one of the problems is that you don't check for cases where `left` is higher than `right`. That can easily happen. Consider that in the very first call of `sort`, `partition` returns 0 (pivot position). Then, you call:

```
sort(array, left, p - 1);
```

which turns into

```
sort(array, 0, -1);
```

That's where negative indexes can be generated.